# Finding the class name of the On-Screen Keyboard?

Tags: c#, keyboard, dllimport, on-screen-keyboard

I am attempting to use this [code sample](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/5772-Bring-e-window-Front-set-It-Active-window.aspx) to control the Windows XP On-Screen Keyboard (OSK.exe) from a C# (.NET 3.5) Winforms application:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);  
[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
private void BringToFront(string className,string CaptionName)        
{            
   SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(className,CaptionName));        
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{            
   BringToFront("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");                            
}
```

How do I determine the accurate className?  I assume that the CaptionName is 'On-Screen Keyboard'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the classname is: "OSKMainClass"

Here is the code I used to find this. It's just a simple C# Forms App

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hWnd =  FindWindow(null, "On-Screen Keyboard");
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(128);
        GetClassName(hWnd, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
        MessageBox.Show(buffer.ToString());
    }
```

Got this from the following sources [Activate Any Window With API](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/activate-window-api)
 and [MSDN GetClassName function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582(VS.85).aspx)